# notification displayed differently depending on whether app is in foreground or background

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm having trouble with notifications on Android. I use the code below to generate a notification on the device whenever a GCM message is received by my app. However, it's producing unexpected results.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService implements Constants {
    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("msg");
        sendNotification(message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.gcm_notification_channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.gcm_notification_channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(GCM_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name,
                    importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setSound(defaultSoundUri,
                    new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_COMMUNICATION_INSTANT)
                        .build());
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                GCM_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentTitle("My Title")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

If a GCM message is received whilst the app is open (not just running, but actually open on the screen), then the resulting notification has only a title, and doesn't show the message. [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1neHn.png) demonstrates this case. Further, if I send multiple GCM messages to the device whilst the app is in the foreground, only one is displayed.

If a message is received whilst the app is either closed or running in the background, the resulting notification shows only the message, and has no title. [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAre8.png) shows the two messages side-by-side - the bottom one was received with the app in the foreground, the top was received with the app in the background. If multiple messages are received whilst the app is in the background, all are displayed (in contrast to what happens when the app is in the foreground). [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlTb8.png) shows that multiple messages are displayed when they're received with the app in the background.

Also, the notification only appears as [heads-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4p0m.png) when the app is in the foreground.

Finally, if received in the foreground, the resulting notification does nothing when tapped. However, if received in the background, the notification opens the app when tapped. Not really bothered by this, just thought it might be indicative of the problem.

FYI: when testing, I tried both keeping the GCM message the same every time, as well as varying it. Both scenarios gave the same result.

### What I'd like to figure out:

- How to get both the title and message to display regardless of whether app is in foreground or not. This is the most important.
- How to get the notification to appear as heads-up when the app is in the background.

Just to pre-empt any responses saying not to abuse heads-up, it's the most important feature of the app (the app must notify users of certain events in real-time), according to our users.

### Update:

Bas van Stein's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534444/1983144) allowed me to figure out why the either only the title or message was displayed.

As he correctly pointed out, when the app is in the background, GCM messages are handled by the system. This drove me to inspect the script that is used to send messages by the backend. I realised that the person who wrote this script had sent the message within the `title` field of the `notification` field of the GCM message, and there was no `body` field. So I corrected this issue, and the notifications displayed correctly (for app in background).

This also allowed me to realise that the line `String message = data.getString("msg");` in `onMessageReceived` was returning `null`. I changed the method as follows:

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Bundle notification = data.getBundle("notification");
    String title = notification.getString("title");
    String message = notification.getString("body");

    sendNotification(title, message);
}
```

Then I added `title` as a parameter to `sendNotification` and changed the line that sets the notification title to: `.setContentTitle(title)`. Now notifications are displayed correctly when the app is in the foreground.

Further, I added a `static int` to the class that I use as the notification ID (incremented every time), so now multiple notifications display correctly.

**Still not solved:**

I'm still unable to have notifications appear as heads-up when the app is in the background. I tried adding `"priority": "high"` to the GCM message `notification` payload, but this had no effect - apparently this is the default for a GCM notification anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be only a part of the complete solution but here we go:

**First issue**, the background and foreground notifications seem to be generated by two different functions, you can test this by applying a break point in your code and attach the debugger. You will likely see that the background notification is not triggering the break point in this code. Perhaps you miss a manifest service?

**Second issue**, that only one notification is being shown is because of this line:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

The `0` here is the notification id, if you create multiple notifications with the same id it will overwrite the notification instead of showing a new one.

**Third issue**, that the application is not opened on notification tab, is because there is no intent attached to the notification you generate in your code.

You can use something like this for an intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
             PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
```

The intent is being called when you click on the notification, this could be any intent so you can open a special activity for example.

Hope this brings you in the correct direction.